# koma-classes: DIV for 14.0pt and used papersize not defined

Tags: fontsize, koma-script

Whan using KOMA-script article class with 14pt I got following warning:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:
Package typearea Warning: DIV for 14.0pt and used papersize
(typearea)                not defined!
(typearea)                Using DIV=1.
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to fix this warning?

The whole example is as follows:

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and
features are listed below, to help you get started. If you have a question,
please use the help menu (``?'') on the top bar to search for help or ask 
us a question. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just let it calculate a DIV value and tell it a papersize:

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt, paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and
features are listed below, to help you get started. If you have a question,
please use the help menu (``?'') on the top bar to search for help or ask 
us a question. 
\end{document}
```

If you don't like the calculated value, you can tell `typearea` which value to use: `DIV=12` for example.

You should only use `utf8x` if `utf8` is *really* not enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As os utf8: yes, I normally use this, x-variant came to me from onpine sample on overleaf dot com.